# How to convert smarty functions to zend functions

Tags: zend-framework, smarty, zend-form

I have written custom smarty functions to work with Zend framework and now I would like them to be rewritten to zend structure, plz suggest how can I do that ? thanx. Here is the sample code for the same...

```
function smarty_function_render_table($params, &$smarty)
{
    extract($params);

    $sSortTableBy  = $smarty->get_template_vars("sortTableBy");
    $bSortTableOrderAsc = (boolean) (strlen($smarty->get_template_vars("sortTableOrder")) > 0 ? strtolower($smarty->get_template_vars("sortTableOrder")) == 'asc' : true);
    $iSortTablePage  = $smarty->get_template_vars("page");

    Adx_Sort::getInstance()->multiSort($data, $sSortTableBy, $bSortTableOrderAsc);

    $columnSettings = $smarty->get_config_vars($id);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analog of the Smarty plugins are Zend View Helpers. You can write Zend View Helpers to make similar job as Smarty plugins did. Zend View Helpers is a class derived from the Zend_View_Helper_Abstract abstract class. View object is already accessible there via view public class member. get_template_vars is not needed - you can just get view custom vars directly from View object.

```
<?php
class Zend_View_Helper_Table extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract {

    public function table($params) {
        extract($params);
        $sSortTableBy = $this->view->sortTableBy;
        $bSortTableOrderAsc = (boolean) (strlen($this->view->sortTableOrder) > 0 ? strtolower($this->view->sortTableOrder) == 'asc' : true);
        $iSortTablePage = $this->view->page;
        return Adx_Sort::getInstance()->multiSort($data, $sSortTableBy, $bSortTableOrderAsc);
    }

}
```

After you had created view helper, you  can use it directly in every view script via direct calls:

```
<?=$this->table($params)?>
```

Comment: what should I replace with for the following smarty methods when converting to Zend_View_Helper:  $smarty->get_config_vars($id), $smarty->_get_plugin_filepath($sSmartyPluginType, $sPluginName)

Comment: You see, ZF Views is completely different from Smarty. So it's not necessary to have direct analog for some Smarty functions. As I know, there is no some special ZF View config, so no analog for get_config_vars method. You must rethink your plugin and your code. Ask yourself, what you try to do with such methods and then it will be much more easier to find appropriate solution with ZF Views.